# Using Parallel Processing in C# to test a site's ability to withstand a DDOS

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, parallel-processing, ddos

I have a website and I am also exploring Parallel Processing in C# and I thought it would be a good idea to see if I could write my own DDOS test script to see how the site would handle a DDOS attack.
However when I run it, there only seems to be 13 threads in use and they always return 200 status codes, never anything to suggest the response wasn't quick and accurate  and when going to the site and refreshing at the same time as the script runs the site loads quickly.

I know there are tools out there for penetration tests and so on but I was just wondering why I couldn't use a Parallel loop to make enough concurrent HTTP requests to a site that it would struggle to load fast and return a response. It seems I get more problems from a Twitter Rush just by tweeting out a link to a new page on the site and the 100s of BOTS that all rush concurrently to the site to rip, scan, check it etc than anything I can throw at it using a Parallel loop.

Is there something I am doing wrong that limits the number of concurrent threads or is this something I cannot control. I could just throw numerous long winded search queries that I know would scan the whole DB returning 0 results in each request as I have seen this in action and depending on the size of the data to be scanned and the complexity of the search query it can cause CPU spikes and slow loads.

So without a lecture on using other tools is there a way to throw a 100+ parallel requests for a page to be loaded rather than a max of 13 threads which it handles perfectly.

Here is the code, the URL and no of HTTP requests to make are passed in as command line parameters.

```
static void Attack(string url, int limit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IN Attack = {0}, requests = {1}", url, limit);
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, limit, i =>
        {

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = limit;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            int statuscode = Convert.ToInt32(webResponse.StatusCode);

            Console.WriteLine("iteration {0} on thread {1} Status {2}", i,
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, statuscode);
        });
    }
    catch (AggregateException exc)
    {
        exc.InnerExceptions.ToList().ForEach(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Exception: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: what framework or core version do you use? I had an issue with .NET Core 2.1 that we were not able to control ConnectionLimit and it was always equals 2

Comment: A DDOS attack literally stands for a *Distributed* attack.  You're using one machine.  The attack isn't distributed.  To find a vulnerability that can be exploited by a *single* machine making requests is a far more significant vulnerability indicating some serious problem by the server that it can be so easily brought down.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await may be a starting point to consider, rather than unnecessary spinning up of threads with `Parallel`. Also, set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.8 just once rather than repeatedly.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a single machine, limited by the performance of its network adapter, would be capable of generating enough traffic to bother a purpose-built web host - regardless of how you program the traffic "generator".

Comment: I know a DDOS attack stands for distributed DOS but I am basically getting that every day from Twitter Rushes. SIte posts one tweet with a link in it and it gets 100's of BOTS hitting that linked page all at same time. Sometimes causes problems sometimes doesn't but I just wanted to try and simulate requesting as many pages as possible to see if I cause a problem. Obviously if it was all run on multiple machines at the same time it would cause x (n x machines) problems but I don't have that as I'm not doing a real DDOS just attempting a simulation if possible

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like:

```
        var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);

        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            _ = await client.GetAsync(url);
        }
```

Comment: The `await` serializes the requests. You could just remove it to make all operations run concurrently, or even better store the tasks in an array or list and `await` them with `Task.WhenAll` at the end.

Comment: Could you please add in the assemblies neded for this to work as when searching for SocketsHttpHandler I get info to add System.Net.Http which don't do anyutjing. So if yuou can supply the assemblies I need for this then thst would be great

Comment: @MonkeyMagix do you use .NET Core or .NET Framework

Comment: I am using .NET 4.6.1 I guess there are some assemblies I need to add to get that last piece of code to work as new System.Net.SocketsHttpHandler(); is all in red asking if I have forgotten to add an assembly and I have using System.Net & System.Net.Http in my using section at the top and cannot find another relevant assembly in the list when going to add a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `Parallel.For` method is using threads from the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). The initial number of threads in the pool is usually small (comparable to the number of logical processors in the machine). When the pool is starved, new threads are injected at a rate of one every 500 msec. The easy way to solve your problem is simply to increase the number of the create-immediately-on-demand threads, using the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 10);
```

This is not scalable though, because each thread allocates 1MB of memory for its stack, so you can't have millions of them. The scalable solution is to go async, which makes minimal use of threads.

Comment: This answer might be improved by adding more info (e.g. code sample) for the last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, the last code snippet > _ = await client.GetAsync(url); just gave me errors with no fixes. I cannot find an assembly I do not have  and  I would have like to compare them if possible e.g time to make a X HTTP requests , no of 200 status codes, no of threads, any downtime on the site etc, or slower response speeds etc. So a an example using async would be good If I can get it to work,

Comment: @MonkeyMagix you may find this article helpful:  [How to make multiple web requests in parallel by using async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await)