# Using Await to run parallel HTTP requests

Tags: c#, http, parallel-processing, async-await, ddos

So this is a carry on from > [[Using Parallel Processing in C# to test a site's ability to withstand a DDOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398458/using-parallel-processing-in-c-sharp-to-test-a-sites-ability-to-withstand-a-ddo/61401067?noredirect=1#comment108883319_61401067][1])

I used this MS KB article as a base for my example except I don't want to run it from a button click but a console script that just starts and then fires the "Attack" method which loops through X no of the same URL, and returns when it does. This [example from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await) is just making 3 requests to Microsoft URLS.

For the sake of just making it more like the KB article I have just replaced the button click with the Main program called when the console app runs which in turn calls Attack() which is ONLY (at the moment just trying to obtain 3 URLS). In the real code I have a loop but I need to get this first bit working so I can understand what I am doing wrong.

However all I get when I run it in a command prompt is....

```
C:\Users\XXX>"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DOSBot\DOSBot
\bin\Release\DOSBot.exe" "https://www.google.com" 1000
10/05/2020 00:00:00: starting script
```

then it ends, no returning messages from the HTTP requests which I was expecting.

The code for the console script is below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace AsyncExample_MultipleTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        // Replaced the MS KB article example of hitting a button with just a Main constructor that runs from the console. I am passing arguments in at the moment URL and no of Requests to make but not currently using them as I want to understand why the MS KB example of making 3 requests is not working
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {

                string url = args[0];
                int no = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);

                ShowDebug("starting script");

                // Attack DOS = new Attack(url,no);
                Attack DOS = new Attack();

                // Moved from the Attack() constructor but made no difference
                DOS.StartAttack();

                // The job just seems to end with no error message and DOS.StartAttack() seems to be skipped over
            }
        }

        public static void ShowDebug(string msg)
        {
            string debugmsg = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + ": " + msg;

            Console.WriteLine(debugmsg);
        }
    }


    public class Attack
    {
        private int Counter = 0; // will hold no of actual HTTP requests completed
        private string URL; // URL to hit
        private int ReqNo; // No of HTTP request to make

        public Attack()//string url, int reqNo=100)
        {
            this.URL = "http://www.google.com";// url;
            this.ReqNo = 100; //reqNo;

            //Tried calling this from here but now from the Main Program Constructor but makes no difference
            //this.StartAttack();
        }

        // Tried calling this from the constructor above (commented out), and now from the main Program but neither do anything different
        public async void StartAttack()
        {
            await CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
        }

        // This would be replaced by my loop with one URL to request and X no of times to request it.
        private async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
        {
            // Declare an HttpClient object, and increase the buffer size. The  
            // default buffer size is 65,536.  
            HttpClient client =
                new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };

            // Create and start the tasks. As each task finishes, DisplayResults
            // displays its length.  
            Task<int> download1 =
                ProcessURLAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
            Task<int> download2 =
                ProcessURLAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx", client);
            Task<int> download3 =
                ProcessURLAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);

            // Await each task.  
            int length1 = await download1;
            int length2 = await download2;
            int length3 = await download3;

            int total = length1 + length2 + length3;

            // Display the total count for the downloaded websites.  
            Program.ShowDebug("\r\n\r\nTotal bytes returned:  {total}\r\n");
        }

        async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
        {
            var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            DisplayResults(url, byteArray);
            return byteArray.Length;
        }

        // Why is this not firing on return of the HTTP request?
        private void DisplayResults(string url, byte[] content)
        {
            // Display the length of each website. The string format
            // is designed to be used with a monospaced font, such as  
            // Lucida Console or Global Monospace.  
            var bytes = content.Length;
            // Strip off the "https://".  
            var displayURL = url.Replace("https://", "");
            Program.ShowDebug($"\n{displayURL,-58} {bytes,8}");
        }
    }
}
```

So the DisplayResults method is not being called at all and in theory from what I have read it should be fired when the HTTP response comes back with the no of bytes etc. However I cannot see it running at all.

Am I missing a reference or something? I am using .NET 4.6.1 on a 64bit Windows laptop in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Hint: If you don't await `StartAttack`, then your program execution moves onto the next line of the `Main` method, and then the next line, and then your program ends. Also note that as of C# version... uh, 7.1? Async main methods are possible.

Comment: The problem here is that your program exists after invocation of `DOS.StartAttack`. Since, the main does not wait for the method execution completion that's why you don't see `DisplayResults ` being invoked. Change `public async void StartAttack()` to `public async Task StartAttack()` and invoke as `DOS.StartAttack().GetResult().GetAwaiter();`. Alternatively, you can use the async main method.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Note sure if this sort of thing should be posted on SO?

Comment: When I change in the constructor public Attack(), this.StartAttack() to this.StartAttack().GetResult().GetAwaiter(); - I get the error that GetResult() is not a method (which it isn't in my class). - If i change the Main method in program which is what runs initially and creates the class with the (hopefully) looping in parallel HTTP requests to public async Main(string[] args) - I get "the type or namespace async cannot be found" - Also if I change Main to public async void Main(string[] args) I get "program does not contain a static Main method for entry point" - a bit more example code pls

Answer (score 3):

There are a few important principles to understand with asynchronous programming:

1. Asynchronous != parallel. There is nothing "parallel" going on in your code.

   - "Parallel" means that two lines of code are executing at the same time. This can only be done with multiple threads. It's all about how things *run*.
   - "Asynchronous" means that you continue executing code while one piece of code is waiting for a reply from something external (network request, file system, etc.), instead of sitting there idle, waiting. It's all about how things *wait*.
2. Since you're continuing to execute code while you wait, you need some way of knowing when the request has actually finished. That's what a `Task` object is for. That's why any asynchronous method should return a `Task`. If it does not return a `Task`, you will never be able to know when it's done or *if* it actually finished successfully.
3. This brings us to what `await` does. The `await` keyword acts on a `Task` object. When `await` acts on an incomplete `Task`, the method *returns*. If the method signature indicates that it should return a `Task`, it returns a `Task`. If the method signature is `void`, then nothing gets returned - but the method still returns. The rest of the method is signed up as a "continuation", meaning that it will run once the waiting is done (and depending on the circumstances, when the thread it started on is available again).

Knowing all this, let's walk through what's happening in your program:

1. `Main()` calls `DOS.StartAttack()`.
2. `StartAttack()` runs and calls `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()`.
3. `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()` runs.
4. `ProcessURLAsync()` is called. Once the network request is sent, an incomplete `Task` is returned. That `Task` object will tell you when the reply is received.
5. The same thing happens for the other two calls to `ProcessURLAsync()`.
6. At `await download1`, because `download1` is an incomplete `Task`, `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()` returns its own incomplete `Task`.
7. Execution returns to `StartAttack()`.
8. The `await` keyword sees the incomplete `Task` returned from `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()` and returns. Because the method signature is `void`, it returns nothing.
9. Execution returns to `Main()`. Since there is nothing else to run there, your program ends.

The problem here is that, because `StartAttack()` is `void`, you lose your way of knowing when the asynchronous requests are done. To fix this:

1. Change `StartAttack()` to return a `Task` instead of `void`.
2. `await DOS.StartAttack()` in `Main()`
3. Change the signature of `Main()` to:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

That is, as long as you're using C# 7.1 or later. That's when the `Main` method could start returning a `Task`.

Microsoft has some very well written articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). They are worth the read. That link is just the first article. You'll find the rest in the table of contents on the left of that page.

Comment: Awesome explanation on "Asynchronous != parallel"!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I did start of with a parallel loop and multi threads but it only went up to 13 threads being used so I thought of async so I could fire, fire, fire quickly but not finish until all responded. My VS2017 C# version said "C# latest major version (Default)" and had a build error on the Main method saying "Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point". So I changed C# version to the highest no 7.3 and then it built and ran. I had this code as you said some time back but the errors threw me. How do you keep C# version to latest as it obv wasnt

Comment: "Latest *major*" might mean 7.0. Try selecting "latest minor version".

Comment: Yes latest minor version worked. Didnt even realise I had to keep that updated thought it would just update as C# got updated with .NET in windows updates. Cheers for that got it sorted now, going to put task responses into an array/collection to collect the responses of each async http request so I can collect all the status codes/response times etc. I know there is  max on threads that can be spawned and also at TCP level isnt there a limit on concurrent http requests? Wouldnt either prevent this test app from working as it should. A Twitter Rush would be a good test 100 BOTS from 1 link